# InteractiveShell attribute

Tags: python, ipython

I got the error message:

**AttributeError: 'InteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'Completer'
WARNING: Failure executing file: <./test.py>**

I have windows 7, neurodebian 6.0.2 and ipython 0.10

could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What is  `test.py`? You might want to try upgrading IPython.

Answer (score 0):

Your python code test.py has `InteractiveShell` object which doesn't have Completer attribute. This is what the error message says. Check the `InteractiveShell` class and look for the `Completer` attribute.